# Cannot display UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: swift, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

I meet a question. I am using following code to display UIActivityIndicatorView. My requirement is to be able to create an UIActivityIndicatorView and display it when I click the button with tag 1, if I click other buttons the UIActivityIndicatorView will be removed from the super view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 lazy var acLoad:(UIActivityIndicatorView) = {
        let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.white)
        myActivityIndicator.center = view.center
        myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()
        return myActivityIndicator
    }()
    //more code
    @objc func btnAction(sender: UIButton){
        switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            print("created")
            view.addSubview(acLoad)
            acLoad.startAnimating()
        default:
            print("removed")
            acLoad.stopAnimating()
            acLoad.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

The above doesn't work, I can get the print log after click, but UIActivityIndicatorView doesn't display, any ideas?

Comment: Works for me. Note that the spinner's color is white, which might be the same color as your view's background...

Comment: Use Medium or Large Style. The rest of the styles are deprecated, Also the one you're using is white.

Comment: try bringing subview to front

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `UIActivityIndicatorView` might be misplaced (wrong frame value) - so it is not visible to you.

```
print("created")
view.addSubview(acLoad)
acLoad.startAnimating()

// Add this line in your button tap code
// It will tell you where it is placed inside your view
print(acLoad.frame)
```

If you find that it's frame is not where you want it to be, just fix your layout code and it will be where you expect it to be.

Another note - `myActivityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true` makes it automatically hide on `stopAnimating()` call. So you can add it only once, not remove-add every time.

Also check your `view.backgroundColor` vs `acLoad` style.